# Create a url structure for my blogs based on categories and sub-cats

Tags: customization, permalinks, menus

My blog design heavily relies on categories and sub-categories. I would like the url structure to be dependent on that. How can I make the url's support the same?

I would like it to be like: `http://www.mywordpressblog.com/categoryname/subcategoryname/postname.html` It should also support further sub-categories if any.

And if I have any pages, It should follow the same structure just that it should be substituted by the page name.

***Further info:***

> I am using Wordpress
>   3.0.1 and hence am using the custom menu feature which allows me to
>   combine my pages and categories into
>   one awesome menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following as a permalink structure;

```
/%category%/%postname/
```

The category slug is added to the URL. Subcategories, if any, appear as nested directories.

So you end up with ;

- /category/your-post-slug/

And if subcategories are used

- /category/subcategory/your-post-slug